# Cant access button in behind span generated from updatepanel

Tags: jquery, css, vb.net

I cannot appear to access a element that is within a span using jquery I am wanting to add a class to it but it appears cause my button is being added at run time via update panel which is in a span with a unique id its not finding the  button. Its not updating the graphic when i click but yet its adding to the database fine and gets to my console log message fine so no its working. But not changing the colour of the font awesome icon.

I am using this to search for the button to add class i constructed.

```
  $(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');
```

The above line is not finding the button

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".btnAddFave").click(function () {
               var productId = $(this).data("product-id");
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/dynamic/Favourite.aspx/AddToFavourites",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ 'productId': productId }),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(xhr.responseText);
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert(response.d);
                                $(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');


                                console.log('do i get past here');
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.d);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                });
       </script>
```

This is the button in quesiton which can be 20 on a page of this button with various ids.

```
<span id="ctl00_BodyContentHolder_lblfavourite-xxxx"><button class="btnAddFave" id="btnAddFave_xxxx" type="button" value="Add To Favourites" data-product-id="xxxx" data-customer-id="xxxx"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: rgb(0, 124, 122);"></i> </button></span>
```

XXXX is just our product codes which i hide for security.

**Edit 2**
To clear up some confusion in my OG the font awesome icon is nested within my button tag as a  element as was only way I could get the icon to show as the following.

Basically each product will have this button favourite and its that that I need to be able to change its font awesome icon colour based on successful completion

[image]

Comment: You are looking for the class .btnRemoveFave but the class for the button you posted is .btnAddFave

Comment: @IsmaC. yes cause when i add I want to change the remove icon color but i think i see what your sayin going to test something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search logic isnt working because $(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart') will return an array if there are more then one button with class 'fa-heart'.

SO to assign any value you should iterate this array as shown below.

```
$.each($(".btnAddFave").find('.fa-heart'),function()
{
$(this).css('color', '#007c7a');
});
```

Comment: its not each of them I am wanting to do its only the one i clicked on at that time @amit

Comment: But your html doesnt show that "fa-heart'" is in btnRemoveFave, Can you please provide full html

Comment: it does show as a <i> element amit inside the button so please look at the code again please

Comment: Ok I will get back in 15 mins.  On the way home

Comment: Yes i can see class "fa-heart" but that isnt inside "btnRemoveFave", where is btnRemoveFave?  please provide html with this class

Comment: Are you trying to click "btnAddFave" ? because <i> is inside this class and not inside "btnRemoveFave"

Comment: i will just my question to show more clearly i already stated that it was in side the <i> and that is the one i need to change i need the post to happen on btnADDFave which does works that part is fine but its getting the icon to appear clicked color is the problem

Comment: i added more detail within my description please see edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153212/discussion-between-amit-wadhwani-and-rogue1nib).

Comment: $(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart') will find the <i> if its inside .btnRemoveFave , but as per your html <i> is not inside , As per your html <i> is within btnAddFave,     Did you get what i am trying to say?

Comment: Yes i do but how is it not inside the button as its in the </b is their a way to change the html so the icon appears same but then the above would work

Comment: Ping me the html which says <i> is inside button which has class "btnRemoveFave"

Comment: amit I dont think you get me surley if its still within the scope of the  </button> tag does that not mean its within button ? code is already above as said

Comment: May be i am getting confused apology for the same,  Following is the html u pasted <span id="ctl00_BodyContentHolder_lblfavourite-xxxx"><button class="btnAddFave" id="btnAddFave_xxxx" type="button" value="Add To Favourites" data-product-id="xxxx" data-customer-id="xxxx"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: rgb(0, 124, 122);"></i> </button></span>     THis does not show any <i> inside "btnRemoveFave",     IN this html <i> is inside "btnAddFave"  am i right?

Comment: ah I am sorry  you are correct so that code above will work then

Comment: Yes , Ohh god fortunately i succeded in explaining you, hehe anyways,  Please mark my suggestion as answer if it helped